# Representation within a RKHS framework

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, kernel-trick

Given a p.s.d kernel $Q$, can minimization/maximization of $Tr(X^TQX)$ over X be represented within a reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) framework? If there is a primary concern with the trace function being unbounded(for maximization) or trivial zero-solution(minimization);  you may consider constraints over $X$; for example-say $X$ being orthogonal. Am trying to see if I can fit this in an RKHS framework.

Also, a few thoughts around this function using hilbert-schmidt norms are as follows: I do see that  $TrX^TQX$ can be represented as $Tr[(SX)^T(SX)]=||SX||^2_{HS}$, using the hilbert schmidt norm where $S$ is the p.s.d square root of Q. (Ex: $S=U\lambda^{1/2}$, where $Q=U\lambda U^T$ is the eigen-decomposition of $Q$).

Comment: May you help us to understand your original problem first, without introducing a RKHS?

Comment: You have a symmetric positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrix $Q$, which we may decompose as $Q=S S^\top$, and you want to minimize $\textrm{tr} (X^\top Q X) = ||S X||^2_{HS}$, where $X$ is an ortogonal $n\times n$ matrix. Is this description correct?

Comment: @Zen I want to see if there are any connections over the minimization problem with RKHS.

Comment: OK. But just to make it clear: my description without the introduction of a RKHS is correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct..

Comment: If that is the case, I do believe that there is a RKHS solution of your problem. I'm not an expert on RKHS theory, but take a look at this RKHS tutorial: www.stat.lanl.gov/staff/CurtStorlie/rkhs_tutorial_12-06-2010.pdf

Comment: Is there a particular section or equation or page you want to refer me to, based on your observations in this paper ?

Comment: I'm studying RKHS techniques in other contexts, but I will try to help you. This week I will borrow Berlinet's book from the library. I'm sure it has a lot of useful information on your problem.

Comment: That would be great Zen..Look forward to it.

Comment: Just read section 1.1.

Answer (score 3):

Hilbert-Schmidt norm in the RKHS as you describe has been used in statistics for a while.

Hilbert-Schmidt Independence Criterion (HSIC) has been successful in capturing statistical dependences. See Gretton and coworkers' papers:

- A Gretton, O Bousquet, A Smola, B Schölkopf. Measuring statistical
  dependence with Hilbert-Schmidt norms. Algorithmic learning theory,
  2005
- K Fukumizu, A Gretton, X Sun, B Schölkopf. Kernel measures of
  conditional dependence. 2008